# Decrypting text using c++

Tags: c++, encryption

I want to decrypt a text using this code. But I can't seem to make it work. Can somebody help me? My editor keep saying that line 29 will never be executed, and does using return 1; correct?

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i, x;
    char str[100];

    cout << "Please enter a string:\t";
    cin >> str;

    cout << "\nPlease choose following options:\n";
    cout << "1 = Encrypt the string.\n";
    cout << "2 = Decrypt the string.\n";
    cin >> x;

    //using switch case statements switch(x) 
    {
        //first case for encrypting a string case 1: 
        for (i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); i++)
            str[i] = str[i] + 2; //the key for encryption is 3 that is added to ASCII value 

        cout << "\nEncrypted string: " << str << endl; {
            return 1; }

        //second case for decrypting a string case 2: 
        for (i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); i++)
            str[i] = str[i] - 2; //the key for encryption is 3 that is subtracted to ASCII value 
        cout << "\nDecrypted string: " << str << endl;

        cout << "\nInvalid Input !!!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi it is not clear what you are trying to do? Encrypt? What is the encryption? Also we can't see line numbers please point to the line that you think is the problem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code has formatting issues as well as typos. The main problem that I inferred from the description that you'd written is `return 1` in middle of the code. I think you should avoid that. Instead put a `break` statement. Also add `default` case label before the line where you are printing *Invalid Input*.

This code may help you:

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() { 
  int i, x; 
  char str[100];
  cout << "Please enter a string:\t"; 
  cin >> str; 

  cout << "\nPlease choose one of the following options:\n";
  cout << "1 = Encrypt the string.\n"; 
  cout << "2 = Decrypt the string.\n"; 
  cin >> x; 
    
  switch(x) 
  { 
  case 1: 
    for(i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); i++) 
    str[i] = str[i] + 2;
    cout << "\nEncrypted string: " << str << endl; 
    break;
          
  case 2: 
    for(i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); i++) 
    str[i] = str[i] - 2; 
    cout << "\nDecrypted string: " << str << endl;
    break;
  
  default:
    cout << "\nInvalid Input !!!\n"; 
  }  

  return 0; 
}
```

*Sample Run:*

```
Please enter a string:  jgnnq
Please choose one of the following options:
1 = Encrypt the string.
2 = Decrypt the string.
2
Decrypted string: hello
```

*PS:* It's quite conventional to return non-zero exit code *only* when an error is encountered. It wasn't required in the middle of the code where no error was present. If you wish, you can put `return 0` in place of the `break` statements, but that's surely not recommended. You can obviously use it inside `default` case label, it's quite justified to use `return 1` there, but instead I would recommend just using `cerr` instead `cout`. There is actually no need of returning NZEC in your program. :)

*Enhancements:* Try using C++ STL classes like [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and functions like [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GH3DrNuHlSSwaqg0) is some code for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

All your code, except for a few variable declarations, is outside of any function. That is not valid. It looks like you intended the code to be inside `main`, but `main` holds only

```
int main() { 
  int i, x; 
  char str[100];
}
```

The function ends at the closing curly brace `}`.